# Website Not Loading Fully in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, google-chrome, web

I have a website http://avocettechnologies.com/avocetiq/

In Firefox it is working cool but in chrome when opening first time it'll work fine but when i refresh the page or reload the intro part(the transition and stuff) will not load, in inspect i can see the code but in browser it won't appear, if i clear the cache it'll work fine and if i reload again same problem

and the website is built with anjularjs

Thank You

Comment: I have the same thing in both, may be a local cache issue

Comment: You shouldn't wrap window load event inside document pseudo ready event. When page is cached, this could be problematic. And in jq3.x, this would cause even more issues (not sure about jq2.x)

Comment: how to fix that, or how to clear the cache each time user refresh the page,

Comment: @A. Wolff  can you please specifically tell me what to do, i'm a kinda new to web development

Comment: Look at [this script](http://avocettechnologies.com/avocetiq/js/scripts.js), any event bound to `window` object shouldn't be wrapped inside `document` ready event. That's said, you are asking for debugging your whole website, this is not the purpose of SO. You need to investigate further on your side

Comment: @A.Wolff i'll go through the script, but site is working fine in firefox, i wonder why not in chrome. Thanks for your time,

Comment: @MrRobot How window load event is handled across browser can differ. This could explain it but i'm really not sure this is your issue here.